# Errors in code, pstricks

Tags: pstricks

I want to write an equation with some arrows above and under with text. Below is my code. When I compile this code i get errors and I don't understand why. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-bezier}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{question}[1]{arc=1mm,colframe=cyan,before
skip=11pt,after skip=11pt,breakable,colbacktitle=cyan,colback=white,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1}

\begin{document}

        \begin{question}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{pspicture*}(-0.1,-1.4)(0.1,1.6)
                    \rnode{A}{\psframebox{$\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma$}} $=$ \rnode{B}{\psframebox{$\alpha(\beta + \gamma$)}}
                    \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=90]{->}{A}{B}
                    \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
                    \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=-90]{->}{B}{A}
                    \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
                \end{pspicture*}
            \end{center}
        \end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you delete the `\centering` command the whole thing seems to break again. It's like some package is missing, or there's a misplaced curly brace, but I don't think either is true. Maybe something about how you formatted `\begin{pspicture*}`...

Comment: You need to compile in XeLaTeX, first. Then, when I do that, it gives one error on the `\centering` line. (See comment above). I think you formatted `pspicture` correctly. I'm not really sure what's wrong. It gives 8 errors when the `\centering` line is removed.

Comment: @heather: One can *also* compile with  ` pdfLaTeX` with the `auto-pst-package`.

Comment: @jalex: The `breakable` option seems unknown to `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Bernard, can't you also compile with `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`? Though, I said XeLaTeX because that is easiest...

Comment: @heather: the `pdf` option does work for me any more. I have to load `auto-pst-pdf` explicitly at the end. `XeLaTeX` is not always the easiest, and it doesn't always give the expected result. A problem with the drivers, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was to add a `\leavevmode` on entering the environment. It's better to use `centering`instead of the `center` environment, to avoid unwanted vertical spaces.

You don't have to specify the dimensions of the `pspicture` environment (not starred!), and if you use `auto-pst-pdf` to compile with `pdflatex`, you can use the `postscript` environment instead.

I suggest a simpler way to code: put the contents of the equation inside a `\[ \]`, and used `\boxed` from `amsmath` rather than the unnecessary `\psframebox`.

Here are both codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-bezier, auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{question}[1]{arc=1mm,colframe=cyan,before
skip=11pt,after skip=11pt,colbacktitle=cyan,colback=white,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1}%breakable,

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    \leavevmode
    \centering
    \begin{postscript}%
        \rnode{A}{\psframebox{$α\beta + α\gamma$}} $=$ \rnode{B}{\psframebox{$α(β+ \gamma$)}}
        \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=90]{->}{A}{B}
        \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
        \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=-90]{->}{B}{A}
        \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
    \end{postscript}
\end{question}
\bigskip
\begin{question}
    \leavevmode%
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}
    \[%
        \begin{postscript}
            \rnode{A}{\boxed{α\beta + α\gamma}} = \rnode{B}{\boxed{α(β+ γ)}}
            \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=90]{->}{A}{B}
            \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
            \ncbar[nodesep=5pt,angle=-90]{->}{B}{A}
            \naput{\text{{\small some text}}}
        \end{postscript}
    \]%
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]